# Why does Surtur say that Thor is Asgard's doom?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, thor-ragnarok

At the beginning of *Thor: Ragnarok* Surtur tells Thor, "I am Asgard's doom and so are you". Isn't Thor the good guy? Then why does Surtur say this?

Comment: Surtur is the guy who starts Ragnarök. Thor is part of Ragnarök when he battles with tha big snake "midgårdsormen" (don't know English translation)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Surtur tells him that because

### he'd be the one that will initiate the Ragnarok.

Near the end, you can see that Thor wasn't able to kill Hela, so, in order to do that, he asks Loki to put the Surtur's crown in the eternal flame, so Surtur can destroy Asgard along with Hela.

> **Thor:** Asgard's not a place, it's a people. This was never about stopping Ragnarok...it was about causing Ragnarok.
>
> **Thor:** (to Loki:) Go to the vault. Surtur's crown. It's the only way.

Comment: So Surtur can see future

Comment: It's not clear in the movie, though.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Not necessarily. Surtur is old, so he probably knows about Hela and he is a good judge of character. He knows that Ragnarok will eventually happen - and he knows that it will destroy Hela - so he presumes that Thor will eventually have to use him to stop Hela - it is not a 100% sure, but if he knows Asgards history and some of Odins secrets it is a pretty good bet.

Comment: I'm sure there were prophecies regarding Ragnarok as well. I can't remember off-hand if that was mentioned in the movies.

Comment: @krillgar the prophecies were definitely in the movie.

Comment: It was in the beginning of the movie before Surtur and Thor started to fight.

Comment: Then the prophecies would lend more credence to Surtur (and many others) to figure out that Ragnarok was imminent. It'd be pretty easy to deduce that Thor would fit the roles of the prophecy.

Comment: @Falco "he knows that it will destroy Hela - so he presumes that Thor will eventually have to use him to stop Hela " - pretty sure that's not what's going on. In the beginning of the movie, it appears that Surtur is expecting to be able to initiate Ragnarok before Hela even returns to Asgard.

Comment: @A J So how did Sutur know that in the beginning of the movie?

Comment: @Nazgul Since Surtur knows about the prophecy already, it's possible that he has heard how it might go.

Comment: I'm not clear on how Surtur would know that Thor will do what he did at the film. do he have some kind of ability to see the future?

Comment: @Vishwa Please see the comment thread from the beginning.

Comment: @AJ I did, doesn't give a clear answer though. knowing about prophecies is one thing, knowing for sure Thor will do as how he did at the end is completely different thing. also why did no one suspected about Loki? or some other powerful beings(enemies of asgard) to cause Ragnarok?

Comment: @Vishwa Although, it's not clear in the movie, but he probably knew how it all will happen.